# Why does my GPU render have a lot more noise than my CPU with the same settings?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I was test rendering ian hubert's splash screen blender file when i noticed that my CPU render is much cleaner than my GPU render. How could that happen? I used the exact same setting for both of the renders, 128 Samples, no denoiser, no adaptive sampling. I am using Ryzen 5 4600H and GTX 1650 Mobile.

- CPU Render:
  [image: CPU]
- GPU Render:
  [image: GPU]

  I don't know if this is normal or not. If it's not normal, i would appreciate any help to get rid of this issue. This is the Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1krvqJd035Jh8_4Ljx1ANsv7pz5anSJ-z/view?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes this is normal because there are differences, CPU is slower but more precise and GPU is faster but less precise, that's simple as it gets but it is much more complicated if you start to read about it... Also you are using volumetrics and CPU handles volumes much better than GPU

Comment: Thank you for the answer! For the volumetrics, I think ian hubert used Mist pass in the compositing tab, it's not volumetrics.

Comment: It is volumetrics, there is volume cube named Cube.044 that has Volume scatter with 0.001 density

Comment: okay thanks for the info, I'm not that experienced with it.